# ALSA, TinyALSA support in Android Things for Raspberry Pi 0.5.1-devpreview

Tags: android-things

The 0.5.1-devpreview BSP for RPI3 comes with libtinyalsa.so, libalasautils.so but seemingly no adb shell commandline support for audio.

We are designing a custom audio board (with audio processor) for use with Android Things and Raspberry Pi and we would typically use ALSA utilities and custom kernel drivers for accessing this board under Raspian.

It is possible the default Android Things I2S peripheral drivers and Peripheral Manager support the stream interfaces we need (the same way the VoiceHat drivers were wrapped), but we have little to no information on the default drivers in the RPI3 BSP, and we don't have any information on how to override the default drivers in Android Things without a distro rebuild.

Seems silly to write a Native C++ low-level peripheral driver when so many audio processor companies already provide ALSA-ready ASoC drivers for device source tree use.

Best practices for writing your own audio driver for Android Things?

Comment: It’s not clear that what you’re asking is on-topic for SO as much as I’d like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The [VoiceHat](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/voicehat) driver is one example of how to do a userspace audio driver.

If you're using a custom audio board, you should be aware of the audio chip the board uses. Looking at that chip's datasheet, you should be able to use the same peripheral I/O (UART, GPIO, I2C, SPI) to configure the connection and read/write data over the I2S bus.

In the [Google Assistant](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant) sample, the app registers the VoiceHat at the beginning of the activity and unregisters it at the end of the activity.